# Kubelet custom path monitoring

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kubelet

I'm running kubernetes 1.8.5 and was wondering if there is a way to tell the Kubelet to monitor /var/lib/docker instead of / on the host.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Kubelet documentation page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/):

Other than from a PodSpec from the apiserver, there are three ways that a container manifest can be provided to the Kubelet.

- File: Path passed as a flag on the command line. Files under this path will be monitored periodically for updates. The monitoring period is 20s by default and is configurable via a flag.
- HTTP endpoint: HTTP endpoint passed as a parameter on the command line. This endpoint is checked every 20 seconds (also configurable with a flag).
- HTTP server: The kubelet can also listen for HTTP and respond to a simple API (underspec’d currently) to submit a new manifest.

It is not quite clear what do you mean by "monitoring", so here is a list of all path-related command line arguments to the Kubelet binary:

> `--boot-id-file string` Comma-separated list of files to check for
>   boot-id. Use the first one that exists. (default
>   "/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id")
>
> `--bootstrap-checkpoint-path string` Path to the directory where the
>   checkpoints are stored
>
> `--bootstrap-kubeconfig string` Path to a `kubeconfig` file that will
>   be used to get client certificate for kubelet. If the file specified
>   by `--kubeconfig` does not exist, the bootstrap `kubeconfig` is used
>   to request a client certificate from the API server. On success, a
>   `kubeconfig` file referencing the generated client certificate and key
>   is written to the path specified by `--kubeconfig`. The client
>   certificate and key file will be stored in the directory pointed by
>   `--cert-dir`.
>
> `--cert-dir string` The directory where the TLS certs are located. If
>   `--tls-cert-file` and `--tls-private-key-file` are provided, this flag
>   will be ignored. (default `/var/lib/kubelet/pki`)
>
> `--cloud-config string` The path to the cloud provider configuration
>   file.
>
> `--cni-bin-dir string` The full path of the directory in which to
>   search for CNI plugin binaries. Default: `/opt/cni/bin`
>
> `--cni-conf-dir string` The full path of the directory in which to
>   search for CNI config files. Default: `/etc/cni/net.d`
>
> `--container-hints string` location of the container hints file
>   (default `/etc/cadvisor/container_hints.json`)
>
> `--docker-tls-ca string` path to trusted CA (default `ca.pem`)
>
> `--docker-tls-cert string` path to client certificate (default
>   `cert.pem`)
>
> `--docker-tls-key string` path to private key (default `key.pem`)
>
> `--dynamic-config-dir string` The Kubelet will use this directory for
>   checkpointing downloaded configurations and tracking configuration
>   health. The Kubelet will create this directory if it does not already
>   exist. The path may be absolute or relative; relative paths start at
>   the Kubelet's current working directory. Providing this flag enables
>   dynamic Kubelet configuration. Presently, you must also enable the
>   `DynamicKubeletConfig` feature gate to pass this flag.
>
> `--experimental-mounter-path string` [Experimental] Path of mounter
>   binary. Leave empty to use the default mount.
>
> `--init-config-dir string` The Kubelet will look in this directory for
>   the init configuration. The path may be absolute or relative; relative
>   paths start at the Kubelet's current working directory. Omit this
>   argument to use the built-in default configuration values. Presently,
>   you must also enable the `KubeletConfigFile` feature gate to pass this
>   flag.
>
> `--kubeconfig string` Path to a kubeconfig file, specifying how to
>   connect to the API server. (default `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig`)
>
> `--lock-file string` The path to file for kubelet to use as a lock
>   file.
>
> `--log-dir string` If non-empty, write log files in this directory
>
> `--pod-manifest-path string` Path to the directory containing pod
>   manifest files to run, or the path to a single pod manifest file.
>   Files starting with dots will be ignored.
>
> `--resolv-conf string` Resolver configuration file used as the basis
>   for the container DNS resolution configuration. (default
>   `/etc/resolv.conf`)
>
> `--rkt-path string` Path of rkt binary. Leave empty to use the first
>   rkt in $PATH.
>
> `--root-dir string` Directory path for managing kubelet files (volume
>   mounts,etc). (default `/var/lib/kubelet`)
>
> `--seccomp-profile-root string` Directory path for seccomp profiles.
>   (default `/var/lib/kubelet/seccomp`)
>
> `--tls-cert-file string` File containing x509 Certificate used for
>   serving HTTPS (with intermediate certs, if any, concatenated after
>   server cert). If `--tls-cert-file` and `--tls-private-key-file` are
>   not provided, a self-signed certificate and key are generated for the
>   public address and saved to the directory passed to `--cert-dir`.
>
> `--tls-private-key-file string` File containing x509 private key
>   matching `--tls-cert-file`.

You can set the Kubelet configuration by providing a [config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/) with the `--config` parameter during the Kubelet start.

To modify existing Kubelet parameters(CentOS example):

1. Edit /usr/lib/systemd/syste/kubelet.service
2. Restart the Kubelet:

   ```
   systemctl daemon-reload  
   systemctl restart kubelet
   ```